# Using media query to resize website but text not wrapping when resizing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a media query to re-size the about me window when the max-width hits 960px but the text does not wrap under the image, some of it stays to the side of the image. I have it set so the About me section shrinks 50% when it hits 960px. Could anyone please help, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Here is my html and css:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {

    /* how to make header stay at the top of the page and cover top*/
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: #666666 4px solid;
    overflow: auto;
    /*width: 270px; */
}

header li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}

h2.namebox {

    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    border: 1px black;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 31px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: Georgia;

}

ul.navbox {


    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    color: #777777;
    
   
}

li a:last-child {
    border-right: none !important;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: green;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

li {

    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    /*text-decoration: none; not removing links*/
}




h1.line {

    color: #4aaaa5;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}


body {

    width: 960px;
    background-image: url(http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Textured-Stripes-Grey-Seamless-Patterns-For-Website-Background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: auto;
}

div.content{


    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
    
}
div.section {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #777777;
    width: 650px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.image {

    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
div.contactbox1{


    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #4aaaa5;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    
}


hr.hrline {


    float: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

h3.line {


    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: center;
    padding: 0;
}

footer {


    background-color: #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: teal 6px solid;
    text-align: center;
    /* how to make it cover the entire bottom portion of webpage */
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
        
    div.section {

        width: 50%;
        height: auto;

    }

    div.contactbox1{


        
        
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2 class="namebox">Dude</h2>
        <ul class="navbox">
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <section>
            <div class="section">
            <h1 class="line">About Me</h1>
            <hr>
            <img class="image" src="file:///Users/vitamind/Desktop/Basic-Portfolio/assets/images/Webp.net-resizeimage.jpg">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <div class="contactbox1">
            <h3 class="line">Connect with Me</h3>
            <hr class="hrline">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_square_color-48.png">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/github_square_black-48.png">
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/overflow-48.png">
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy;Copyright 2017 
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are floating the image, so text will be on the side as much as it can before wrapping.

You can add the following to your image inside your media query to push the text below.

```
.section img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or, if you want to avoid resizing the image, you can just set `float: none;` instead.

```
.section img {
  float: none;
}
```

[**Working Resizable Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/zckm8Lx3/2/) (used lorempixel image just for demo)